# jQuery index() in relation to all visible siblings

Tags: jquery, indexing

I'd like to fetch the index of an element in relation to all visible siblings.

A `td.index()` does fetch the index of the td to all other td siblings.

But what when some of those TDs are set to `display:none`. I want to exclude them when calculating the index. `td.index(':visible')` does not seem to work.

Comment: that would not give you the true index, why not just use an if statement so if it is visible carry on actions, else do nothing :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var $td = $("#theTD")

$td.siblings(":visible").andSelf().index($td);
```

The above should do what you're asking.  Basically get the set of elements you want to search within and then get the index of your element within them.

http://jsfiddle.net/3NYY9/

**EDIT:** As of jquery 1.8 `andSelf` has been deprecated and `addBack` should be used in its place:

```
var $td = $("#theTD")

$td.siblings(":visible").addBack().index($td);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3NYY9/45/

Comment: Instead of adding back yourself to a collection, which seems a little hacky, why not just get your parent's visible children?  $td.parent().children(":visible").index($td);

Comment: @user1689571 That is nearly equivalent.  The only difference is that if the element itself is not visible, your way will return -1.  If that's not a concern then your way is perfectly valid.

Comment: @James-Montagne Not hacky at all now that you put it in that perspective!  Not a concern with my code, but thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Perfect for modifying it for elements of specific classes too!

Answer (score -3):

Visibility and Display are quite different in CSS. What you would want to do is to set the visibility property as hidden for those other TD elements instead of setting display:none

Comment: `:visible` in jQuery is a bit different.