# update index for each item after hidding some of them

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>1</span>323</div>  
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>2</span>525</div>  
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>3</span>727</div>  
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>4</span>454</div>
```

Now I have a button click by which first and third `.itemp` are hidden and want to update `.spanindex` text to show index+1 of visible items:

```
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>1</span>525</div>
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>2</span>424</div>
```

I tried using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496046/jquery-index-in-relation-to-all-visible-siblings) but it doesn't work for `each` version

**js**

```
$('.spanindex').each(function(){            
   $(this).text($(this).siblings('.visible').addBack().index('.spanindex')+1);
})
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by selecting the `:visible` elements, then use the `index` parameter of the function you can provide to `text()` to update the value. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.itemp:eq(0), .itemp:eq(2)').hide();
  
  $('.spanindex:visible').text(function(i) {
    return i + 1;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemp"><span class="spanindex">1</span> 323</div>
<div class="itemp"><span class="spanindex">2</span> 525</div>
<div class="itemp"><span class="spanindex">3</span> 727</div>
<div class="itemp"><span class="spanindex">4</span> 454</div>

<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnUpdate", function (event) {
  $('.itemp:visible').each(function(i,v){   
     $(v).find('.spanindex').text(i+1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='itemp' style="display:none"><span class='spanindex' >1</span>323</div>  
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>2</span>525</div>  
<div class='itemp' style="display:none"><span class='spanindex'>3</span>727</div>  
<div class='itemp'><span class='spanindex'>4</span>454</div>

<input type='button' value='Update' id='btnUpdate'/>
```